# Kivy: is there a touch state like button state?

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

For touch events, I know there is on_touch_down which triggers when you touch the screen, on_touch_move which triggers when your touch position changes , and on_touch_up which triggers when touch is released but I need a function to be called while touch is active including when the touch position does not change. For example, with buttons I just bind a function to the button's state so while the button state is "down" the function is called. Is there something similar I can do with touch events?

Example Using button.state:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string("""

<ButtonR>
    size:self.size
    pos:self.pos

<RootWidget>
    button1:button1
    button2:button2

    ButtonR:
        id:button1
        text:"press button to move"
        size_hint:0.2,0.2
        pos:0,0

    ButtonR:
        id:button2
        text:"press screen and move"
        size_hint:0.2,0.2        
        pos:0,200

""")

class ButtonR(Button):
    def move(self):
        self.center_x+=1

class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    button1=ObjectProperty(None)
    button2=ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self,dt):
        #Bottom button only moves if clicked on
        if self.button1.state=="down":
            self.button1.move()

    def on_touch_move(self,touch):
        #Top button moves only when touch event moves position
        self.button2.move()

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        app=RootWidget()
        Clock.schedule_interval(app.update,1.0/60)
        return app

if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I need a function to be called while touch is active including when the touch position does not change

The touch becomes active when you receive `on_touch_down`, and is no longer active when the `on_touch_up` is called for the same touch. Whatever logic you want, you can just call it via these.

> while the button state is "down" the function is called

I don't know what you mean by this - if you just want to call a function when a touch happens, use `on_touch_down`.

If you want to call a function conditional on a touch being present, simply store a list of current touches (you can add to it when you get an `on_touch_down` and remove when you get an `on_touch_up`) and work with it however you want.